# findbugs not generating html report

Tags: ant, report, findbugs

the below is my taskdef in a ant build file

```
<target name="findbugs">
   <echo message="${findbugs.home}"/>
   <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}"
     output="html"
     outputFile="E:\reports\findbugs-report.html" 
     effort="max"
     reportLevel="low" >
      <sourcePath path="${basedir}/enterpriseapplication/**" />
      <class location="${basedir}/**/*.class" />
   </findbugs>
</target>
```

I checked file permissions on the directry every thing is fine. I get the cli output but no file is generated. 
Any help please.

Comment: Did ant generate an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some problems with the paths that I has put in the configuration. Fixing those paths resolved the problems. Also we need to be sure that the file system has permissions to create/modify files where the result file is placed.
Thanks for all your answers/comments guys.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem before. It seems that findbugs is unable to create the file.
Create an empty file named **findbugs-report.html** in the directory E:\reports\

Hope that helps.

---

> Do not forget to mark an answer as the accepted answer if it solves your question.